# Keep a submit button inside parent form perfectly round w/ CSS

Tags: html, css

**Context:** I have a web app with a form where the submit button is displayed to the right of an input of type "text"

[image: a form where the submit button is displayed to the right of an input of type "text"].

**Desired Goal:** I would like the submit button on this form to be round on all screen sizes. While the button is round on desktop-sized screens, it becomes stretched into an oval on mobile-sized screens (example pic linked above)

**What I've Tried:** I've tried tagging the width / height elements of the button in my CSS file with !important, thinking this will keep its dimensions constant and reduce the width of the text input instead. However, the width of the button and the text input both shrink when the screen width is reduced.

**Ask:** What CSS code can I use to keep the button circle on all screen sizes?

Please find below my code:

```css
.box {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

form.item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button {
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 322px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
      <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
          <p><%=item.name%></p>
        </div>
      </form>

      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

Also, this is my first Stack Overflow question post, so please feel free to provide any advice for improving my future posts. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: _“However, the width of the button and the text input both shrink when the screen width is reduced.”_ - because you _allowed_ for them to do that. Go read up on the `flex-shrink` property.

Comment: This would help out to create responsive round button


  : http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/Jyjjx/45/